# How to stop rendering a react component until some async function has fetched some data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, async-await, axios

I have a react HOC for private routes which should render the private route only if the config has permissions , now im using inversify for injectiing a service, the service calls the loadConfig function whenever an instance is created using useInjection , my app needs to be loaded again to make this work and shows error that it cannot access the properties of the permission array.
How can i add some delay to make sure the array is accessed only once the loadConfig has been called by the service constructor.

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useInjection } from "inversify-react";
import ConfigService from "../Services/_configService";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";


function render(c: JSX.Element) {
  return c;
}

const ProtectedRoute = (Component: any, route: string) => {
  const currentUser: any = useSelector((state) => state);
  
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(true); 
  const config = useInjection(ConfigService)
 
 
 
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (config.Permissions.length > 0) {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    }, 2000);
    console.log(config.Permissions)
  }, [config]);
 

  if (isLoading) {
    return    <span className="indicator-progress" style={{ display: "block" }}>
   <span className="spinner-border spinner-border-sm align-middle ms-2"></span>
  </span>
  }

  return currentUser && config.Permissions && config.Permissions.includes(route)
    ? render(Component)
    : <Navigate to="/" />;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

inside my  service im calling the function like this

```
  constructor() {
    this.loadConfigData();
  }
  async loadConfigData(): Promise<void> {
    const response = await get(API_ENDPOINTS.CONFIG_URL).then((response:AxiosResponse<Data>)=>response)
    const config = response; 
    this._permissions=config.data.permissions
    this._configuration=config.data.configuration
}
```

Comment: My approach has always been to render some kind of indication that an operation is in progress, as opposed to trying to prevent rendering entirely.  What should your page look like while the operation is in progress?  Render _that_.  Then change state when the operation completes.

Comment: that error does not show now, i added one more condition to check if config.Permissions is undefined, now its working but upon initial rendering the spinner keeps showing until i refresh the page.